# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: PBKDF2 algorithm not found error

Tags: docker, keycloak, pbkdf2

I built a new keycloak image using the instructions mentioned in https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/ under "Building image with Keycloak from different sources". It was working fine till last week but when I tried to build new image again, I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: PBKDF2 algorithm not found` error on starting of the container. Anyone has any idea about this error? I am guessing it's happening while running the add-keycloak-user script but I am not sure.

Comment: Hello @sagun, did you find the issue?

Comment: I too am having this issue but I'm not sure of its origin because it doesn't work on all systems

Comment: we observed that with RHEL 8.2 we are able to install keycloak, but with RHEL 8.4, it breaks with this error.  Still working on what the difference is at the OS level (crypto library packages?) that causes the failure.

Comment: We are still having the same issue and can't upgrade to next version. Here is the thread https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/9916 where it's being discussed. The workaround they are proposing is not working for me.